# Can I install New Relic on a Bluehost Shared Hosting Plan?

Tags: wordpress, shared-hosting, newrelic, bluehost

I want some more insights into my wordpress site so I signed up for a New Relic account. But they're asking me to install some agent by typing in commands and I have no idea where to do that or how to access a command line.

I use shared hosting with Bluehost so I have access to cPanel. I've never typed anything into a console to manage the server - the icons have covered everything I need. So far.

Is it even possible to install this on my shared hosting plan? If so, where do I get the command prompt, do I need FTP? I've tried to follow the instructions, but there're some strange words like "yum", "rpm" and what not. What are these, and how do I run them?

Is there a wordpress plugin that I can just install and have everything done automatically for me?

If anyone could point me to some clear step by step instructions as to how to go about this, I'd be very grateful...

Thanks!

Comment: Most if not all of this sounds like stuff you should be asking your host and possibly the New Relic people.  But something tells me you're gonna end up a bit disappointed; shared hosting and shell access often don't come together.  :P Particularly not the kind of access that'd let you install system software (via yum/rpm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is shell access.  According to their features page at http://www.bluehost.com/cgi/info/hosting_features, they support shell access via SecureShell (SSH).  This is fairly common.

Download an SSH client like PutTTY and connect to yourdomain.com, or if you are on a Mac, open the Terminal app and type "ssh yourdomain.com" (with your web site's domain name).  You can then run commands.

However, this probably will not get you what you need.  You mentioned yum and rpm commands, which are system-level software installation tools.  You'll need root access to do that, which you certainly cannot do on a shared hosting account.

These types of tools are really intended for application service providers.  I'm fairly familiar with New Relic's products.  I'm guessing you are trying to install the server monitor tool.  You probably don't need to worry about that one since Bluehost should be monitoring their servers for you.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to install the performance monitor. Guess I'll have to find another way to do that...